# Is there a quick way to find out where the colours for an MUI component is coming from?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When experimenting with the theme I often want to try to set the colour of a specific part of a component to a different colour. For example, the inner, grey, borders for a `DataGrid` component.

If I want to do this across the entire app, the generally best method seems to be to use the palette to set the colour, making it so that any other similar scenario will use that same colour. (Supposing there was a "lite" data-grid that uses the grey borders, for example.)

However, finding out what part of the palette that component involves a huge amount of trial and error, changing all parts of the palette to bright colours until finally the component I'm looking at changes. This is especially time consuming if it turns out that the colour doesn't come from the palette at all.

I've not found any mention on the documentation about what palette colours a component uses.

Is there some way I can easily find out where the colour for a part of a component's coming from?